# Error: Oracle ora-01732 data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Tags: c#, sql

I have an insert query to a View like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Vbilling003(Recno,Invno,Advamount,pricode,Recamt,
    Curcode,Plansk,Cusid,RecDate,ServType,ServGroup,PaidType,
    Userid,Sertypesk,OutLetsyskey,usersyskey)
Values ('MRYNG1140200718','I131200916',
    'WiMAXCor(Corporate)(01/12/2013 - 31/12/2013)',
    'WiMAXCor',130,'USD',2011101409363013071,
    '000952','20140214','WIMAX','WIMAX00001',1,
    'soscthuthuhan',2008100710542865027,
    2008092612192119003,2013103103260590019)
```

But when I run it, I get the error:

> oracle ora-01732 data manipulation operation not legal on this view

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Well, don't you think it would be helpful to show the view statement?

Comment: You are not allowed to insert into the view.

Answer (score 0):

You insert normally into tables. Only simple views are able to accept inserts. If a view contains expressions or functions, is derived from more than one table, a join operation was used to create the view or the view contains virtual columns derived from functions or expressions, then the view may only be queried.